# Photorec custom signature

Tags: recovery, data-recovery, qnap

Recently I have lost my database files after server (Qnap) reboot.
I need to recover the MYD files.
I'm using the Photorec to recover my files which uses file signatures.

I know that MYD files doesn't have common file signature.

I've recreated the database from the earlier backup (on local machine) just to check if the signature changes when new data inserted and it seams like the signature bit is not changing.
I'm not sure if that means I have the signature of the file that I'm looking for.
I've tried to create a photorec.sig file and entered MYD 0 0x00010065fe00000100003101aa70010f00 which are the first 34 chars of the hexdump result.
I've saved this file into the current working directory and ~/.photorec.sig and tried to recognize the MYD file with fidentify_static which always returns unknown.

I think there is something wrong with the signature file that I've created. Can anyone tell me how to make sure that the signature file is created correctly and placed to the right place on qnap?

Comment: Or should I use something else other than the Photorec?

Answer (score 0):

Run `fidentify` with the file/directory as the parameter:

```
[kmaster@adsl ~]$ fidentify /home/kmaster/src/testfiles/sample.pfi
```

See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec